# Reference(address) storage in variable Java

Tags: java, eclipse, object

How can I store the address of one object or variable in another object in Java. Like we do in C++

int a=&b; // b is also int

If I want to pass reference type objects by reference in Java to any method, how can I do this cuz by default they are passed by value.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, basically. *Everything* is passed by value in Java, and there's no way of changing that.

The closest you can come is to create your own generic mutable wrapper type, or use an array of length 1. The wrapper approach makes it much clearer what you're doing, but it's less efficient. You can use [`AtomicReference<V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) as a wrapper type if you want, although its use *implies* that you're concerned about concurrency when you probably aren't.

For wrappers of primitive types, you could either use the `Integer`, `Long` etc classes, or you could write an individual specific wrapper type for each primitive. (Again, the latter would be slightly more efficient.)

Fundamentally though, you should *try* to design your code not to need this. I *very* rarely find it a useful technique. If you find yourself wanting to do it very often, you may be "thinking" in a different language...

Comment: I thought that nowadays we are using AtomicReference instead of an array to simulate such references?

Comment: @Bananeweizen: I think you must have been commenting while I was editing :) Both of these imply something which isn't really relevant though - if I see a use of `AtomicReference`, I usually think there must be some sort of concurrency going on.

Comment: with sun.misc.Unsafe, you can have your Java and eat your C too! ;)

Comment: What are the differences between address and reference in terms of alanguages like java.

Comment: Integer, Long and other wrappers are immutable, so they can't be changed. As I understood, it is the main goal of passing by 'address'.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use addresses in Java. There is simply no such ability. All things are passed by value. When you want to pass an object to be mutated you have several ways:

a) Pass an array:

```
int [] valueArray = new int[1];
valueArray[0] = <your value>;
```

b) Pass a mutable wrapper, which you shoud write by your self.

c) Pass an input int and retur a new value:

```
int a = 5;
a = sqr(a);
```

Comment: Well, there *is* a way, sun.misc.Unsafe, but who wants to go there?! :)

Comment: @sjr I don't see any way even with s.m.U to get the address of an object/primitive. Example? That sounds interesting ;)

Comment: http://javapapers.com/core-java/address-of-a-java-object/ makes for interesting reading

Comment: @sjr Yeah it's well known that you can get the offset of a field or array index (and even then to get the actual address you have to have allocated the object with s.m.U because otherwise the offset alone won't do much good), but that doesn't help to get the address of an object/primitive itself.

Answer (score 0):

There comes a difference from C++ to java. Even though it's not a good practice to use the address of an Object in java, there are ways to get the logical address.

http://javapapers.com/core-java/address-of-a-java-object/

I hope this will help you.